# 'docker-php-ext-install' command not found

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, gitlab-ci

I am taking a deep dive into `Gitlab Ci`, `Docker` and `php`

I am having a problem where a command is failing in the middle of my gitlab ci script...

```
deploy_to_dev:
  stage: deploy
  image: php:5.6
  allow_failure: true
  tags:
  - arc
  variables:
    PWS_IP: 'x.x.x.x'
  before_script:
  - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev git
  - docker-php-ext-install soap
  script:
  - git config --global http.sslVerify false
  - git diff --name-only origin/DEV | xargs php ./scripts/pws_loadgroovy.php
  only:
   refs:
   - DEV
   variables:
   - $CI_PROJECT_ID == "71"
```

`$ docker-php-ext-install soap`

`bash: line 106: docker-php-ext-install: command not found`

I can't tell for sure if this command is being run on Ubuntu or php5.6 .. It seems like this is being run on Ubuntu given the `apt-get update` commands. But is the `docker-php-ext-install` command supposed to be executed from the Ubuntu shell?

How should I aim to fix this problem?

Comment: PHP 5.6? Please don't, it has long reached the end of its support. That said, you can `docker run --rm ...` the image, run the commands inside the created container and find out yourself where the error occurs. BTW: Why did you tag this with "git" and "gitlab-ci"? Please first extract a [mcve], so you know which parts of your project are actually relevant to the problem. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I tagged with git / gitlab-ci because this is being run from a gitlab pipeline. The script I posted above is apart of the .gitlab-ci.yml file. 

Edit - disregard my previous error - I forgot the 'run' syntax: I'm getting a different error:

``ubuntu@npse-gitrunner:~$ sudo docker run --rm -it run php:5.6-cli bash
Unable to find image 'run:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for run, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.``